# Serialization.. String to POJO

Tags: java

I need to convert this String to POJO. Pls tel me how can i do this

This is Just an example

```
Anne12F02PhysicsPassChemistryPassFirstClass
```

This is the string.. Now i need to convert this to pojo

My POJO looks like this

```
Class student {     
    String Name;
    int age;
    char sex;
    List<Subject> subList;
    String classiness;
}

Class subject {
    String subject;
    String result;
}
```

This is just an example.

02 in the string indicates the size of list.

Note ::
And also the length of each attribute is predefined(example.. Name 10 chars.. if there are only 5 chars in the name, then blank space is appended)

The list may again contain a list, the length will be indicated

Answer (score 0):

You need to use substring on the String to get all the different elements. You will then need to use `Integer.parseInt` and similar functions to convert the string to the types you need, and then finally, construct your POJO with the calculated variables.

Also, if one of the elements is a list (which it is), then you will need to create an ArrayList and add each element, depending on the size of the list that needs parsing.

So, a sample would be (assume your input string is called `toPojo`)

```
String name = toPojo.substring(0, 10);
int age = Integer.parseInt(toPojo.substring(10, 12));
```

As this is homework, try finishing the rest off...

EDIT: Follow up

to get the list, do something like

```
// get size of list and loop from zero to the size of the list
// find the index of the first item in the list
// int index = startIndex + loop*itemLength
// toPojo.substring(index, index+sizeOfElement);
```

Comment: Hi, Thats fine.. But when i have list whose size varies, then how can i use substring.. I mean to say as the length of the list varies, how do i find from which index i need to get the next attribute value

Answer (score 0):

If the lengths of the attributes are predefined, you could just use method `String.substring(int, int)` to retrieve each attribute, and then create the POJO out of the parsed values. Something like following code snippet:

```
String input = "Anne12F02PhysicsPassChemistryPassFirstClass";

String name = input.substring(0, NAME_LENGTH); // name length is predefined
String age = input.substring(NAME_LENGTH, NAME_LENGTH + AGE_LENGTH);

// and so on

Student s = new Student(name, Integer.parseInt(age));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your strings have variable length, you might want to write the string length before the string itself, or use some delimiters between the fields, say commas or pipeline characters.